# how to build using env in parceljs

Tags: parceljs

I use parcel to build a frontend app, this is the command I use for build

```
cross-env NODE_ENV=dev parcel build src/index.html --no-minify --out-dir dist/dev
```

to build `production`

```
cross-env NODE_ENV=production parcel build src/index.html --out-dir dist/production
```

In `index.html` there is as usual

```
<script src="app.js"></script>
```

Then in `app.js`

```
import settings from './settings.js'
```

I'd like to achieve something like

`settings.js`

```
if(process.env.NODE_ENV == 'dev') {
  server = 'http://localhost:1235'
} else if (process.env.NODE_ENV == 'production') {
  server = 'http://public-domain.com'
}
```

Comment: Could you give more details as to what errors you are getting, or why this is not working for you?